# Why does an if loop not catch an NA value correctly inside a function in R?

Tags: r, function, if-statement, na

I have a fairly complex function that modifies some character variables. While coding the function, I bumped into a curious problem with handling NA values. I will spare you the complex function and instead present the problem in the MWE below:

```r
# Create an example data frame
df <- data.frame(noun = c("apple", NA, "banana"))

# Display the example data frame
df
#>     noun
#> 1  apple
#> 2   <NA>
#> 3 banana

# Introduce the function 
process_my_df <- function(input_data, my_var) {
  # Create a new variable based on an existing variable
  for (i in 1:nrow(input_data)) {
    if (!is.na(input_data[[my_var]][i])) {
      input_data[[paste0(my_var, "_result")]][i] <- "is a fruit"
    }
  }
  return(input_data)
}

# Call the function to process the data frame
processed_df <- process_my_df(df, "noun")

# Display the resulting df
processed_df
#>     noun noun_result
#> 1  apple  is a fruit
#> 2   <NA>  is a fruit
#> 3 banana  is a fruit
```

<sup>Created on 2023-11-03 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

My question: based on the condition `if (!is.na(input_data[[my_var]][i])) {}` I would expect the following result:

```r
#>     noun noun_result
#> 1  apple  is a fruit
#> 2   <NA>        <NA>
#> 3 banana  is a fruit
```

What's going on?

EDIT:

As a result of the accepted answer below, I added one simple line inside the function and now everything works fine:

```r
# Introduce the function 
process_my_df <- function(input_data, my_var) {
  # Create a new variable based on an existing variable
  
  # But first, "prime" it with NA_character_
  input_data[[paste0(my_var, "_result")]] = NA_character_
  
  for (i in 1:nrow(input_data)) {
    if (!is.na(input_data[[my_var]][i])) {
      input_data[[paste0(my_var, "_result")]][i] <- "is a fruit"
    }
  }
  return(input_data)
}
```

<sup>Created on 2023-11-03 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Is there a reason you are using a `for` loop? you could achieve the same thing by replacing the entire loop with `input_data[[paste0(my_var, "_result")]] <- ifelse(!is.na(input_data[my_var]), "is a fruit", NA)`

Comment: Look what happens when you run `df[["new_col"]][1] <- "hello"` where "new_col" doesn't exist yet. The rest of the values in this new column need to be populated as well so the initial value is recycled. Creating a vector row-by-row is usually problematic. This loop could be replaced by an `ifelse` or something vectorized.

Comment: @MrFlick I suspected something like that, but with the simple example you provided, you really nailed what happens below the hood.

Comment: @jpsmith I actually ended up using an ifelse() statement myself, but this initial "recycling" problem haunted me. But now you guys have solved it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue happens when you implicitly create the new column. If you do it explicitly, it works correctly:

```
# Call the function to process the data frame
df$noun_result = ""
processed_df <- process_my_df(df, "noun")

# Display the resulting df
processed_df
# noun noun_result
# 1  apple  is a fruit
# 2   <NA>            
# 3 banana  is a fruit
```

Comment: If the default should be NA instead of empty string then do this to start. `df$noun_result = as.character(NA)`

Comment: Well, `NA_character_` then if we are being pedantic.

Comment: TIL that that's how to get NA character. I've always done the above while figuring it wasn't right but never bothering to look harder for the proper way.

Answer (score 1):

Given the explanation provided by @Andrey Shabalin, you need an `else` condition

```
process_my_df <- function(input_data, my_var) {
  # Create a new variable based on an existing variable
  for (i in 1:nrow(input_data)) {
    if (!is.na(input_data[[my_var]][i])) {
      input_data[[paste0(my_var, "_result")]][i] <- "is a fruit"
    } else {
      input_data[[paste0(my_var, "_result")]][i] <- NA
    }
  }
  return(input_data)
}
```

Comment: Or just loop over only non-NA lines `for(i in which(!is.na(input_data[[my_var]])))`

Comment: @Andrey Doesn't that just reproduce the original problem with the "recycling" of the initial value?

Comment: @Marcus Thanks you for the solution, I came up with an almost identical solution myself but was left wondering why my initial code didn't work and therefore decided to post this question to SO.